# Java 8 String join should accept Function<E,R>

Tags: java, string, java-8, api-design

Is there any reason why String.join now works only with CharSequence elements ?

It is a bit hard to join elements of different collections to String.

It would be supper easy to add this in the api support:

```
public static <E extends Object, R extends CharSequence> String  join(final CharSequence delimiter, Iterable<E> elements, Function<E, R> stringExtractor)
```

and than to keep the same api:

```
public static <E extends Object> String join(final CharSequence  delimiter, Iterable<CharSequence> elements)
{
    return join(delimiter, elements, Function.identity());
}
```

Than to join the Integers we can simply:

```
String.join(",", IntStream.range(0, 5).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()), elem -> elem.toString())
```

Comment: You're making this way too complicated.  Use the `joining()` collector instead. Precede by `map(Object::toString)` (or other mapping function) as needed.

Comment: Are you asking why such a method doesn't exist? Or is this some sort of an enhancement request for the JDK (because Stack Overflow isn't for that)?

Comment: @BrianGoetz Collectors.joining is good if I want to use streams. I was thinking more about non-stream approach. But ok, fair enough if it was decide that it was too-complicated. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Tunaki just trying to understand why it was not included in the api. I am sure that at some point somebody suggested this and there was a reason why it was not added.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you don't want the `Collectors.joining()` collector on the end of your stream?

**Example Code**

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

numbers.add(5);
numbers.add(6);
numbers.add(7);
numbers.add(8);

String value = numbers.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("-"));
System.out.println(value); // Outputs 5-6-7-8
```

**Working Example**: http://ideone.com/C1EGas

Comment: this is in case if you want to use stream api. I know about the joining collector. The example collection I gave was just dummy example. But thanks anyway for your answer